# Making an opacity text-gradient over a transparent background

Tags: css, html, opacity, gradient

it should look like http://img190.imageshack.us/img190/1686/textgradient.jpg 
 the tricky part is, it should work for opera, canvas..? also important: the transparency is only needed for the big texts in the screenshot.

the text is simple html text in a span tag. the background is a somewhat transparent png, defined as css background-image of the container div.
i'd have no problems with using canvas or something like that for displaying the text.

Comment: Can you please show us your work so far?

Comment: Can you give more detail? - is this to be an image or editable text?

Comment: i'm sorry for the little specifics, i have edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, it was a long day, and i've found a solution by myself.
it uses canvas.

for a canvas with html height 73px and width 720px:

```
var ctx = myCanvasEl.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "53pt Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif";
var gradient = ctx.createLinearGradient(400, 0, 650, 0);
gradient.addColorStop(0, "rgb(255,255,255)");
gradient.addColorStop(1, "rgba(255,255,255,0)");
ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
ctx.fillText(myText, 0, 58);
```

Answer (score 2):

If only [Cufón](http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/) supported a horizontal linear gradient "out of the box" you would have been sorted for an easy `<canvas>` solution. Funnily enough, a conversation on [cufon supporting a horizontal linear gradient](http://groups.google.com/group/cufon/browse_thread/thread/fed18f69083c36ab) was just started in the last 24 hours. The demo below demonstrates Cufón with a vertical linear gradient using `rgba`.

#### Demo: [jsfiddle.net/Marcel/35PXy](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/35PXy/) ([fullscreen](http://jsfiddle.net/Marcel/35PXy/show/))

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this that I can think of is to create a copy of the background image, go into photoshop and create a gradient that's mostly transparent. Then overlay the gradient on the text. That'll work in every browser, I believe.

Comment: the problem with this approach is, that the original background image already is transparent. the result would be, that the text can't be more transparent than the background

Answer (score 0):

You don't need canvas anymore. Use property `background-clip: text` combined with a gradient background with rgba (alpha channel to full transparency).

Here an example:
http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ExperimentsBackgroundClipText/index2.html

It's great but it works just in webkit browser, at this time.

For a more compatible solution you can look at `mask-image` http://trentwalton.com/2011/05/19/mask-image-text/
Similar to the first method, you should fade mask to full transparency to get the effect you want to realize.