# CSS - how to make the end of the word blurry?

Tags: html, css, blur

I really like how twitter blur the end of the long name, when you move the cursor on the box with message.

I would like to try make something similar, with a little difference - I have a DIV (let's say **width: 100px;**) and when a text inside is longer then 100px - then will be the end of the respective text blurred...

Could anyone give me some example/source/advice, how to do that?

Thank you

[image: example]

Comment: Take a look here

[Gradient text][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498601/making-an-opacity-text-gradient-over-a-transparent-background

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/text-fade-read-more/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With the following HTML:

```
<div>
    <span>@someUserName</span>
</div>​
```

And CSS:

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

span::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 3em;
    content: '';
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3GgzU/).

You can, of course, also use percentage widths in the generated content: [JS Fiddle proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3GgzU/1/).

---

**Edited** in response to comments, below, reporting that IE 8 (and presumably lower) doesn't work with the above solution:

> not working for me in IE8 though...

I've updated the HTML to the following:

```
<div>
    <span>@someUserName
        <!--[if ie]>
            <span class="ieFadeout"></span>
        <![endif]-->
    </span>
</div>​
```

And updated the CSS:

```
div > span {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

div > span::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 3em;
    content: '';
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(255,255,255,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(left, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

span > .ieFadeout {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 3em;
    background-color: transparent;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00ffffff', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */

}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo, working in Win XP/IE 8, and Chrome 18 (as before)](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3GgzU/4/).

References:

- [Conditional Comments for IE](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html).
- [CSS Gradient generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/).
- [CSS linear gradients](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/linear-gradient).

Comment: i REALLY like this solution! not working for me in IE8 though..  would you recommend a fall back to an image? or is there a way to get this working in all browsers

Comment: Honestly; I'm not sure. I was under the impression that IE8, at least, [should be able to handle this CSS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc351024(v=vs.85).aspx#generated). I have a feeling that you might have to use conditional stylesheets and, potentially, extra elements in the content, rather than generating content. Sigh.

Comment: I didn't test fully, i was just so pleased when I opened your jsfiddle in chrome i wanted to try it in IE.. maybe its a jsfiddle thing?

Comment: No; it failed in my own IE8 test too. Sigh. Still, see the edits. The later version worked in the WinXP/IE8 that I have access to; hopefully will work for you, too. Also, it didn't lose compatibility with the other browsers, so should be okay. Albeit (unfortunately) messier.

Answer (score 3):

You place another DIV right on top of that and give it a semi-transparent PNG background, which fades from completely transparent to completely white. Something like:

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 100px">
    @GuyKawasaki
   <div style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-image:url(overlay.png)"></div>
</div>
```