# Vertical Text Gradient With Opacity

Tags: jquery, css, text, svg, gradient

I'm trying to achieve the following with CSS3 or jQuery or SVG or canvas but I'm having some difficulties.

[image]

Four things that should be noted:

1. The gradient of the text is veritcal, and there is opacity involved
2. The text could be multi-lined (it's client inputted)
3. There is an outline around the text (text shadow would probably be appropriate. IE support isn't needed.)
4. There is a background image behind it.

The easiest solution is `-webkit-linear-gradient` but as much as I love Webkit, I feel I have a responsibily as a developer to support Firefox, Opera and IE to some extent.

Chris Coyier used in in his [demo](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/gradient-text/) and I added a background image to show it in action:

[image]

Since there doesn't appear to be a cross browser alternative at this time, I will turn to JavaScript and the popular jQuery for answers. Which there are few.

The first is a neat plugin from MRNIX called PXGradient. You can [checkout his website](http://mrnix.ru/pxgradient/) but it's all in Russian. Basically to use that script you enter an array of HEX values and it finds the middle points between them, created a `<u>` tag and a wackload of `<s>` tags in them, all with the content of the parent text. It creates a nice effect.

[image]

While it does support text shadows and background images, it doesn't support opacity. I have came across several other plugins that do this similar hex to hex transition, but none of them support rgba from what I could find.

Stackoverflow comes up with [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498601/making-an-opacity-text-gradient-over-a-transparent-background), and references Cufon. Cufon is great but doesn't allow text shadows.

SVG also comes up, in which I found [this example](http://codepen.io/yoksel/pen/xmshn) but SVG must be a current width and height in which I don't know what this text will be (it's inputted by the client).

[image]

(Unless we can get the height and width of the text and append SVG dynamically. But my SVG knowledge is pretty terrible so I might need some help with that.)

I have looked at CSS options, jQuery plugins, SVG and canvas and I'm not having much luck.

Does anybody have an idea about what I can use? Any solutions will be helpful.

Cheers!

Comment: Couldn't you just use CSS opacity on the containing element in conjunction with the PXGradient plugin? Or are you wanting the opacity to be part of the gradient?

Comment: @APAD1 I am currently doing that, but there's no opacity at the top of the text while there's about a 50% opacity at the bottom. So I would like the opacity separate. I might just contact the plugin creator and see if he can modify to accept rgba values...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This effect is quite easy to achieve in SVG, and will work in all modern browsers, including IE10+.

HTML/SVG

```
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300"/>

<svg width="400" height="300">
    <defs>
        <linearGradient id="textgrad" x2="0" y2="1">
            <stop offset="0.65" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0.7"/>
            <stop offset="0.9" stop-color="white" stop-opacity="0"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <filter id="emboss">
            <feConvolveMatrix kernelMatrix="1 0 0
                                            0 0 0
                                            0 0 -1"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>

    <text class="textblock fading">
        <tspan x="20" y="130">ERGY</tspan>
        <tspan x="20" y="260">SOLU</tspan>
    </text>
    <text class="textblock embossing">
        <tspan x="20" y="130">ERGY</tspan>
        <tspan x="20" y="260">SOLU</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
```

CSS

```
svg {
    position: relative;
    top: -300px;
}

.textblock {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 130px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.fading {
    fill: url(#textgrad);
    stroke: white;
    stroke-width: 0.5;
    stroke-opacity: 0.5;
}

.embossing {
    fill: white;
    filter: url(#emboss);
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/pb6dtgkw/)

Comment: OMG. If I could kiss you, I would! I can use jQuery to see if there's a line break and change the height of the SVG element by that then. This is perfect. Thank you! Thank you!